# ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, angularjs

I have a data structure that is generated by a function. It returns the the last 30 days in reverse order (as  in  11, 10, 9, 8 etc.) as an array of objects.

```
function HoursCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.days = function () {
        var d = new Date();
        var result = [];

        for (i = 0; i < 31; i++) { 
            result.unshift({day:d.getDate() });     
            d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
        }
        return result;
    };
};
```

Here is the output of the function:

```
[ { day: 9 }, { day: 8 }, { day: 7 }, { day: 6 }, { day: 5 }, etc. ]
```

I am using ng-repeat to expose this data as a list:

```
<div ng-controller="HoursCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="day in days">{{day.day}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The li elements are not being generated! What am I missing?

Comment: BTW, any reason you're using `unshift` instead of just looping in reverse?

Comment: Are you getting a stack overflow or Range error in the console? If so, that's because you can't ng-repeat over newly-created-every-time objects -- they get a new scope each $digest. You can fix though by adding a $$hashKey to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call it as a function.

```
ng-repeat="day in days()"
```

Comment: +1 Yes. Yes it will. But he wanted to know why it didn't work, not "what is the best way to do this?". This is why.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting up a function as a method on the scope, just populate a `days` property on the scope:

```js
function HoursCtrl($scope) {
    var d = new Date();
    $scope.days = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) { 
        $scope.days.unshift({day:d.getDate() });     
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    }
};
```

---

For better performance, you might try looping in reverse and using `push` instead of `unshift`:

```js
function HoursCtrl($scope) {
    var d = new Date();
    var counter = 31;
    var date = d.getDate();

    $scope.days = [];
    d.setDate(date - counter + 1);

    while ( counter-- ) {
        date = d.getDate();
        $scope.days.push({ day: date });     
        d.setDate(date + 1);
    }
};
```